# Running Astah on Linux

Tags: linux, java

I'm trying to install and run Astah Professional on my linux machine. I have downloaded the debian package and run the dpkg command. Now when I try to run

```
astah pro
```

I get the following error message:

```
nick@LapBot:~$ astah-pro
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/i386/libawt_xawt.so: libXext.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1845)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
at java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1636)
at java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1634)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1633)
at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1668)
at java.awt.EventQueue.isDispatchThread(EventQueue.java:1043)
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread(SwingUtilities.java:1361)
at JP.co.esm.caddies.jomt.jutil.O.c(X:59)
at JP.co.esm.caddies.jomt.Jude.main(X:104)
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks, in advance! - Nick

Comment: This is where I found a working answer. http://askubuntu.com/questions/674579/libawt-xawt-so-libxext-so-6-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-di/844649#844649

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the program, but that looks as though you need the java dev kit (JDK) and the java runtime (JRE)

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/i386/libawt_xawt.so: libXext.so.6: cannot open shared object file: **No such file or directory**

you could manually install JDK1.8.0, or:

```
apt-get update && apt-get -f upgrade
```

Comment: I have already downloaded and installed the JDK1.8.0, which I am pretty sure means I have also downloaded an appropriate JRE, no?

Comment: apt-get update && apt-get -f upgrade